# Django - ValidationError does not display

Tags: python, django

I recently tried the forms validations and faced an issue with ValidationError().

The form error does not appear in my website when I submit the form.

Here is the code:

**forms.py**

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_titre(self):
        titre = self.cleaned_data['titre']
        if len(titre) < 5:
            raise ValidationError('myError')
        return titre

form = ArticleForm()
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="form-group">TITRE
  {{ form.titre.errors }}
  {{ form.titre }}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def AddArticle(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.user = request.user
        save_it.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

What did I do wrong?

--- EDIT ---

Full **template.html**

```
<form class="form" action="{% url "article.views.AddArticle" %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">TITRE
      {{ form.titre.errors }}
      {{ form.titre }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">SUMMARY
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.summary.errors }}
      {{ form.summary }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">CONTENU
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form.contenu.errors }}
      {{ form.contenu }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.image.errors }}
      {{ form.image }}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">TAGS
      {{ form.tags.errors }}
      {{ form.tags }}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" />
</form>
```

I'll post the full forms.py too, it may help.

**forms.py**

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_titre(self):
        titre = self.cleaned_data['titre']
        if len(titre) < 5:
            raise ValidationError('myError')
        return titre

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['date', 'rating', 'user']

        widgets={
            "titre":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Le titre', 'class':'form-control'}),
            "contenu":forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Le Contenu de votre message', 'class':'form-control'}),
            "image":forms.FileInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Votre Image', 'id':'uploadBtn'}),
            "tags":TagWidget(attrs={'placeholder':'Vos Tags', 'class':'form-control'}),
        }

form = ArticleForm()
```

Comment: Where's the rest of that view? What happens if is_valid is not True? Or if it's not a POST?

Comment: I don't have the rest, I didn't know I needed one, what should I write it the "else:"?

Comment: In that case you would definitely get an exception, because every view must return a response. If your form is not valid but you are not getting an exception, you cannot be using this view at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `else` portion within your view. Here is the general flow of what forms usually do:

1. Users navigate to a page via `GET` which presents them with a form
2. Users fill in the form and submit it by using `POST`
3. If the form is valid, users are directed to a different page
4. If the form is not valid, users are presented with the same page as in step 1 with the validation errors displayed. After users correct them, they are process to step 2.

Here is that flow in django view:

```
def AddArticle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.user = request.user
            save_it.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
       form = ArticleForm()

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form'})
```

I would however look into using class based views in Django. Initially they can seem very confusing but over time you will learn to appreciate them. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/). Another useful [resource](https://ccbv.co.uk/) when learning CBV.

By using CBV, the above can be simplified to:

```
class AddArticleView(CreateView):
    success_url = 'name_of_view_here'
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'template.html'

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^articles/add/$', AddArticleView.as_view()))
```

#### Template

You also need to include the overall form error in the template, in addition to each field errors:

```
<form class="form" action="{% url "article.views.AddArticle" %}" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    ...
</form>
```

Please note that you might need to wrap the errors with some bootstrap markup. More info in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/)

Comment: But the mystery is that the view couldn't possibly have worked the way it is now, so there is something OP is not telling us.

Comment: @Sia can you post your complete form template since currently you only posted  template for a single form field

Comment: not sure as well. try debugging with ipdb to verify that form is indeed invalid and that errors are present in the view. if so, then a bug is in the template. if not, then bug could with with form or view